# What's up with the cycloid-shaped pot in Melville's Moby Dick?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, math-history, calculus-of-variations

People interested in the intersection between mathematics and fine literature may be familiar with the following quote from Herman Melville's famous novel *Moby Dick*:

> It is a place also for profound mathematical meditation. It was in the left hand try-pot of the Pequod [*the whaling ship of Captain Ahab*], with the soapstone diligently circling round me, that I was first indirectly struck by the remarkable fact, that in geometry all bodies gliding along the cycloid, my soapstone for example, will descend from any point in precisely the same time.

Apparently, a try-pot is a large cauldron-like reservoir for the oil extracted from the blubber of killed whales. Melville describes how these pots  are kept neat and shiny by scouring them with soapstone and sand.

Now my question is, is there any special reason why the inside of a try-pot should be cycloidal in shape (radially)? Or is this just a coincidental property of the Pequod's particular try-pot?

Is it the case, for example, that an initially spherical hollow surface in which round abrasive stones are let to roll down at random is eventually ground into a cycloid shape? If so, what would a mathematical proof of that fact look like?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautochrone_curve  where reference is made to your quote.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's true that Melville was obviously referring to the tautochrone property of the cycloid. But my question, which perhaps should have been formulated more clearly, is why this cauldron that Melville describes would have had a cycloid shape in the first place. Was it made like that for a special purpose, was it ground out that way by the scouring soapstones, or just an amusing coincidence?

Comment: My guess is that it is made like that because it improves separation by settling solids at the bottom the slowest, thus leaving gaps for oil to pass through the longest. By the way, this is a really good question.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber That sounds really interesting and plausible.

Comment: The bottom third or so of the *outside* of [this try-pot](http://www.portcities.org.uk/london/server/show/conMediaFile.4045/A-whaling-trypot.html) is very nearly cycloid.

Comment: The link posted by @Peter Taylor has been deleted. Here is a snapshot from the Web Archive that displays the try-pot: https://i.imgur.com/1VBmTjv.jpg